# My AWS ec2 instance is running on ec2-xx-1xx-xxx-24.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000. how do i make it run on ec2-xx-1xx-xxx-24.compute-1.amazonaws.com

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

My AWS ec2 instance is running on ec2-xx-1xx-xxx-24.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8000. how do i make it run on  ec2-xx-1xx-xxx-24.compute-1.amazonaws.com

I am using Gunicorn server server and it is a Django application on Ubuntu server

Comment: an ec2 instance does not run on a specific port - your web app does. change the port for Django and make it 80 rather than 8000

Comment: and check [Gunicorn doc](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.io/en/19.6.0/deploy.html) to see how it can be used to be deployed wiht a reverse proxy

Comment: @FrédéricHenri i changed the port to 80 but now i cant access the site completetly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the same via virtual host in httdp.conf with redirection rule or you can do the same with ELB in which you can mention the request comes on 80 and ELB will forward the same on 8000 port.

Answer (score 0):

This is a two step problem:

You have to configure Django to listen on the right port, and you also have to modify the security group attached to your instance to allow connection on port 80.

You can either allow access from anywhere or from a specific IP/Range of IPs.

An other solution is to create an ELB and configure it to listen on port 80 and send the traffic on port 8080.